# How to make laravel to look for admin model while forget password entering a link?

Tags: laravel

I have multiple authentication system User and Admin.
Laravel make:auth automatically looks for User model.
I want Make:auth forget password to look for Admin Model instead of User model.
Where should i change the code because when i type email in send password reset link then it says no email found because laravel is checking User Model not Admin Model.

Comment: I think you should take a look at Guards, here is good article about it. https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at `config/auth.php`, you have to provide multiple reset password table.

for example:

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Entities\Accounts\User::class,
        ],

        'clients' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Entities\Clients\Client::class,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'users_password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'clients' => [
            'provider' => 'clients',
            'table' => 'clients_password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

In those example I have multiple auth providers: `users` and `clients` therefore I have to have separate password reset table. `users_password_reset` and `clients_password_reset` just copy original password_reset migration and update accordingly.

Comment: but  still it looks for User model. When i type email of Admin Model its says user with that email cannot be found.

Comment: have you check your authentication guards?

Comment: Ok Question Solved Thanks!!